# Variable not being recognized for If Statement

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int H = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter the *insert whatever the formula thing is called*");
        String Form = input.next();
        //System.out.println(Form);
        double Total = 0;

        if (Form.contains("H") == true)
        {
            H = Form.indexOf("H", H);
            //System.out.println(H);
            if (Form.substring(H+1).matches("[1-999].*") == true)
            {
                String M = Form.substring(H+1);
                System.out.println(M);
                int M2 = Integer.parseInt(M);
                Total = Total + (1.008 * M2);
                System.out.println(Total);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Form.substring(H+1).matches("e") == true)
                 {
                       System.out.println("Found 'e'");
                       //System.out.println(H);
                        if (Form.substring(H+2).matches("[1-999].*") == true)
                        {
                        String M = Form.substring(H+2);
                        System.out.println(M);
                        int M2 = Integer.parseInt(M);
                        Total = Total + (4.003 * M2);
                         System.out.println(Total);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        Total = Total + 4.003;
                        System.out.println(Total);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    Total = Total + 1.003;
                    System.out.println(Total);
                }
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------


    }

}
}
```

That is the whole code, but heres the part im having trouble with:

```
if (Form.substring(H+1).matches("e") == true)
                 {
                       System.out.println("Found 'e'");
                       //System.out.println(H);
                        if (Form.substring(H+2).matches("[1-999].*") == true)
                        {
                        String M = Form.substring(H+2);
                        System.out.println(M);
                        int M2 = Integer.parseInt(M);
                        Total = Total + (4.003 * M2);
                         System.out.println(Total);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        Total = Total + 4.003;
                        System.out.println(Total);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    Total = Total + 1.003;
                    System.out.println(Total);
                }
```

The problem I'm having with this small section is that when I try to input "He9", it skips the whole first if statement and goes to the last else statement, but if I put "He" it'll work for the first If Statement and skip the second and go to the 2nd to last else statement (like it should).

And just in case any of you are curious, this is for school project =P.

Comment: Bad practice to name variables with capitals. Makes syntax highlighters think they're classes ;)

Comment: Respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with lowercase letters. Also, choose much better names for them. What do M, M2, H, etc. represent. If you can't name them correctly, that means youdon't really know what they're for, and we do not either. If you can't name them unambiguously, that means your method is too long and should be split. Finally `if (someExpression == true)` is redundant. Just use `if (someExpression)`

Comment: You should also defined named constants for the magic numbers 4.003, 1.003, etc. It's much clearer to see PI, PLANCK_CONSTANT or AGE_OF_THE_CAPTAIN than those repeated meaningless numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Form.substring(H + 1)` does not return `e` as you expect for `He9`, it returns `e9`. Make it `Form.substring(H + 1, 2)`.

Also you don't need to check if something == true in the if statments, that is implicity. Also, check some best practices for naming variables.